# How to resolve Promise inside Map?

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to create a new array using the Map function. But inside the Map function, I need to call an API to get a value. How to resolve the Promise inside the Map function? Because I got this response from the `getTrapTransactionsRefunded` function: `{"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}`

```
const getTapTransactionsRefunded = async (logicalId: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get(`transactions/${logicalId}`);
    if (response.data.length > 0) {
      return response.data[0].transaction_amount_c;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const purchaseList = purchases?.map((purchase: TapData) => {

return {
    id: purchase.id,
    logicalTransactionId: purchase.logicalTransactionId,
    logo: "",
    title: purchase.cardAcceptorNameLocation,
    purchaseStatus: purchase.purchaseStatus,
    amount: Number(purchase.authAmount).toFixed(2),
    loanAmount: Number(purchase.loanAmount).toFixed(2),
    outstandingBalance: Number(purchase.outstandingBalance).toFixed(2),
    purchaseDate: purchaseDateToString(purchase.purchaseDate),
    transactionAmount: getTapTransactionsRefunded(purchase.logicalTransactionId)
  };
});
```

Comment: You can't do that. You have to run a `for await` loop to get the responses and then run a map function to do what you want to do.

Comment: Use the `map` function to build an array of promises (e.g. by using `async`/`await` in the callback), then use `Promise.all`.

Comment: @ArjisChakraborty No, don't use `for await`, there are no asynchronous iterables involved here